# SSIS Export all data from one table into multiple files

Tags: loops, foreach, ssis, export

I have a table called customers which contains around 1,000,000 records. I need to transfer all the records to 8 different flat files which increment the number in the filename e.g `cust01`, `cust02`, `cust03`, `cust04` etc.

I've been told this can be done using a for loop in SSIS. Please can someone give me a guide to help me accomplish this.

The logic behind this should be something like "count number of rows", "divide by 8", "export that amount of rows to each of the 8 files".

Comment: Is there any logic behind the division or you are simply trying to get the data split across 8 files in mostly equal partitions?

Comment: Yes just splitting the data evenly (maximum 8 files)

Comment: It doesn't sound too hard to do if you can describe it succinctly like this. Which part of your code doesn't work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me, it will be more complex to create a package that loops through and calculates the amount of data and then queries the top N segments or whatever.

Instead, I'd just create a package with 9 total connection managers. One to your Data Database (Source) and then 8 identical Flat File Connection managers but using the patterns of FileName1, Filename2 etc. After defining the first FFCM, just copy, paste and edit the actual file name.

Drag a Data Flow Task onto your Control Flow and wire it up as an OLE/ADO/ODBC source. Use a query, don't select the table as you'll need something to partition the data on. I'm assuming your underlying RDBMS supports the concept of a ROW_NUMBER() function. Your source query will be

```
SELECT 
    MT.*
,   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) % 8 AS bucket
FROM 
    MyTable AS MT;
```

That query will pull back all of your data plus assign a monotonically increasing number from 1 to `ROWCOUNT` which we will then apply the modulo (remainder after dividing) operator to. By modding the generated value by 8 guarantees us that we will only get values from 0 to 7, endpoints inclusive.

You might start to get twitchy about the different number bases (base 0, base 1) being used here, I know I am.

Connect your source to a Conditional Split. Use the `bucket` column to segment your data into different streams. I would propose that you map bucket 1 to File 1, bucket 2 to File 2... finally with bucket 0 to file 8. That way, instead of everything being a stair step off, I only have to deal with end point alignment.

Connect each stream to a Flat File Destination and boom goes the dynamite.

Comment: So, issue is resolved, but the answer to your question is another? that's an F.

Comment: @Abbaskhan6428 ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: apologies I'm new to think forum and didn't understand the concept of the tick thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a rownumber with a Script Component (don't worry very easy): http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2010/01/create-row-id.html
or you could use a rownumber component like http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/03/custom-ssis-component-rownumber.html or http://www.sqlis.com/post/Row-Number-Transformation.aspx

For dividing it in 8 files you could use the Balanced Data Distributor or the Conditional Split with a modulo expression (using your new rownumber column):
[image]

[image]