# How to use the object variable as a source for other variable?

Tags: ssis

I have a stored proc that returns a large number of rows. I have to write rows into a text file, 1,000 rows max per file (ie if my stored proc gives 6,500 rows, I have to write them to 7 files: 6 files with 1,000 records and 500 records for the seventh file) in SSIS. Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question will be addressed by a very similar scenario posted in the following link: [SSIS Export all data from one table into multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612375/ssis-export-all-data-from-one-table-into-multiple-files)

The only difference is that you're applying a stored procedure.  You could easily modify your process by sending the results from the stored procedure to a temporary staging table in your database that includes an identity column.  As the stored procedure populates the staging table, the identity column would automatically increment starting at 1 and you would use this as a reference for the process defined in the above link.  That is, you would populate the first file with the records having values 1 through 1000 in the identity column.  The next file would be 1001 through 2000... and so on.  Of course, the export would include all of the staging table columns of data, except the identity column.  Once the export is complete, truncate the staging table in preparation for the next time you run the SSIS package.

Please let me know if this helps.