# SSIS export sql table to multiple flat files based on rowcount

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, export-to-csv, foreach-loop-container

I know this may be a simple task but I have yet to find a simple answer.  I have a large sql table that I want to export into multiple flat files (.csv to be exact) that are 10,000 records each.  I want to do this using SSIS and from what I gather I will need a FOREACH LOOP container.  This is as far as I have got.  As an added bonus, a few of the columns have commas in the data itself so when the file gets delimited by commas  the data still needs to be preserved without taking out the original comma

All the videos I have come across have been using scripts or delimited by the type of data or some other way.  I just want to have csv files based on a set number of records in each file.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Export all data from one table into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612375/ssis-export-all-data-from-one-table-into-multiple-files)

Comment: preserve , in CSV would not possible..

Comment: The possible duplicate is a hard coded way of solving this problem.  It makes 8 of the exact same flat file connection that is evenly be divided.

I need to create a FOR LOOP container that has variables that are passed so that I can dynamically change the number of records per flat file (what if want it to be 100, 10,000  or 100,000 per file?).  This is for a very specific assignment: EXPORT DATA FROM A TABLE TO MULTILPLE FLAT FILES USING FOR LOOP IN INCREMENTS OF VARIOUS SIZE (100, 10,000...?)